# Error is output layer shape in neural network, can't figure out the mistake in dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I am starting out with neural networks. I have built a model, and trained it on my training dataset. But when I try to evaluate the model, I get a dimension mismatch error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_16 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)`. For the life of me, can't seem to be able to figure out where in the model definition its arising from. Any help is appreciated.

Model definition:
[image]

Training:
[image]

Evaluation (error):
[image]

**Code:**

```
# Building a model - build a simple feedforward neural network for this problem.

# Specify all the parameters we will be using in our network
input_num_units = (32, 32, 3)
hidden_num_units = 1000
output_num_units = 3

epochs = 10
batch_size = 128

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, InputLayer



# Define the network/model
model = Sequential([
  InputLayer(input_shape=input_num_units),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(units=hidden_num_units, activation='relu'),
  Dense(units=output_num_units, activation='softmax'),
])



model.summary()


# Compile our network and let it train for a while, with cross validation

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)


score = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: I think you should check the shape of test_x .

Comment: The most important piece is missing: what is `train_x` and `test_x`?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but, did you use to_categorical on your test data as well, with which you are trying to evaluate?

```
y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes)
```

Comment: I just ran one of my old models and missed this part - and got a very similar message - Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: num_classes will be probably 3 - I used 10 classes in this example